# Ng model not able to provide updated value for checkbox in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML Code :**

```
<div id="createConfigManagementDivId" 
    class="panel-portal">
    <h1 class="titlebar ng-binding">
        GUI Configuration Data</h1>


    <div class="grid span-20 centered vlead-2">
    <ul class="tabs">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Boolean Data </a>
                                    <div class="content">
                                         <h2> Boolean Data</h2>
                                        <div>

                                            <div ng-repeat="chk in boolchkbxs">

                                                    <label>{{chk.label}}</label>

                                                    <input type="checkbox"  ng-change="GetBoolValue(chk)" ng-model="chk.Selected" />
                                                </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>


                            </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="text-right buttonbar">
        <button id="applyButton">Apply</button>
        <button id="updateCacheButton">Update GUI cache</button>
        <button id="clearButton" ng-click="clearForm()" >Cancel</button>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


});

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.boolchkbxs = [{ label: "XXXX", Selected: true }];
$scope.GetBoolValue = function () {
    var message = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.boolchkbxs.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.boolchkbxs[i].Selected);
        if ($scope.boolchkbxs[i].Selected) {
            var lableName = $scope.boolchkbxs[i].label;
            message += lableName + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

But I am unable to get the latest value modified by user in checkbox in the above code. $Scope.boolchkbxs[i].Selected always returns true (which is a default value);

Can someone please help me to solve the issue ??

Even I have tried samething for a single checkbox without ng-repeat, still the value it returns default and not the updated value.

The function GetBoolValue is not getting called when i change the value of checkbok

Comment: I've typed your code above, but cannot reproduce the issue. `$scope.boolchbxs`'s value changed every time when check or uncheck the `checkbox` in html. Could you provide complete code?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the complete code in my original post.

Comment: did your html code have syntax error i.e not closing div tag?

Comment: Yes. one Div was missing,i have corrected it, but still the GetBoolValue method is not getting hit :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/AvGKj/  even i have tried this code in my environemnt. But nothig is working.  Is there any environment issue?

Comment: I write in https://jsfiddle.net/AvGKj/935/ based on your code above.

Comment: I got the issue,  we have our own custom JS which is used for adding styles to checkbox, in that JQuery method $source.removeAttr('checked') $source.attr('checked', true) , I guess this is causing the issue.. I am not sure how to combine this with angualr js , so that to get the value of checkbox using ng-model. if ($checkbox.is('.checked'))
                {

$source.removeAttr('checked')
                }
                else
                {
                   $source.attr('checked', true)
                }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MPNz/6/ This solved my issue.. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

GetBoolValue should be called when change the chackbox value. i think this should be you expect. Now you can get the value of selected check box and find the label and calculate message.

Comment: <div>
        <div ng-repeat="chk in boolchkbxs">
                <div class="span-6 vspan-2">
                    <label>{{chk.label}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="span-6">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="GetBoolValue(chk)" ng-model="chk.Selected" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

Comment: In this case, the getBoolValue method is not getting called when i select/deseclect the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to setting the value of checkbox using jQuery. So ng-model value doesn't get updated.

To solve the issue, I have written checkboxWithChangeHandler in my controller ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MPNz/6/)).

**html**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"/> Default
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" checkbox-with-change-handler/> Checkbox with change handler
    </label>
</div>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" ng-model="radio" value="onclick"/> Default
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" ng-model="radio" value="onchange" radio-with-change-handler/> Radio with change handler
     </label>
</div>

<br/>
Checkbox: <span ng-bind="check"></span><br/>
Radio: <span ng-bind="radio"></span>
```

**javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('checkboxWithChangeHandler', [function checkboxWithChangeHandler() {
    return {
        replace: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).change(function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element[0].checked);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
app.directive('radioWithChangeHandler', [function checkboxWithChangeHandler() {
    return {
        replace: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).change(function () {
                if (element[0].checked) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(attr.value);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```